# How to slidedown and animate the width together in sequence

Tags: jquery

How would I slideDown a div and animate the width together.

The jquery docs website is down to look at an example. Could I maybe use the new promise() for this?

I have tried:

```
$foo.slideDown({duration:500},function(){
    $dropDown.animate({"width": 400}, 450);
});
```

And

```
$foo.slideDown({duration:500}).animate({"width": 400}, 450);
```

Both do one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to clear the "queue"

```
$foo.slideDown({duration:500, queue:false}).animate({"width": 400}, 450);
```

Comment: updated the answer after I've seen more detailed question , check the the update

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set height, you can use just animate instead

```
$foo.show().animate({"width":500,"height":500},450);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example doesn't work, because the function you are creating only gets called when the slideDown animation has finished.

The second example does nearly the same thing, just in a different way.

However, if you just call both functions like so:

```
$foo.slideDown({duration:500});
$dropDown.animate({"width": 400}, 500);
```

They should run in parallel (or, more or less, appear to be).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for something like this:

```
W = $foo.css('width')==orgWidth ? 400 : orgWidth;
$foo.animate({height: "toggle", width: W}, 500);
```

[Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/XWpCz/)

Or for just sliding down:

```
$foo.animate({height: "show", width: 500}, 500);
```

[Another Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/XWpCz/2/)